# Go back to previous activity without touching the current

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activity (ACT 1 and ACT 2):

ACT1 contains the button "next" with the code:

```
case R.id.next: 
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ACT2.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
```

ACT2 contains a button "back" no code for now.

so my problem I do not know what change in the button "next" and what to put in the button "back" to:

next: Open ACT2 if it is never open else go ACT2

back: back to ACT1

PS : **I will not destroy "ACT2" if I go back a "ACT1", because I do not want to lose the contents entry**

Answer (score 1):

In the **onClick()** method of **BACK** use **finish()** method, this destroys the current Activity and moves to the previous opened activity.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems u need to come back to act1 on back of act 2 and on next of act 1 to need to go to act 2 ....just start the activity i dont think u need that flag there

Answer (score 0):

try this as per my suggestion..try like that.

```
        // Write code in Next button click Event
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACT1.this, ACT2.class);            
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

        // Write code in Back button click Event
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACT2.this, ACT1.class);            
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

Comment: no he not return an error but it launches "ACT2" next he closes all